# method : "DELETE" in ajax cause *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR* error in the console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a little bit confused that what is happening here.

In my case, I want to delete the dynamically loaded record on my page so I passed the `id` from ajax to PHP like this

```
    $(document).on("click" , "#delete_button" , function(){
        const id = $(this).attr("data-delete_user_id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/deleteUser.php",
            method: "DELETE",
            data : JSON.stringify({id}),
            success: function (data) {
                const res = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    })
```

and simply log the response into the console after deleting the record from the database.

Hence, the console shows me `DELETE https://hamza786504.000webhostapp.com/admin-user-test/api/deleteUser.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Here is the code inside of `api/deleteUser.php`.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json , MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(isset($json)){
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["user_id"] !== $data["id"]){
        $user_id = $data["id"];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";

        if(mysqli_query($con , $sql)){
            echo json_encode(["status" => "200" , "message" => "record deleted successfully!"]);
        }else{
            echo json_encode(["status" => "404" , "message" => "user not found"]);
        }
    }else if($_SESSION["user_id"] == $data["id"]){
        echo json_encode(["status" => "404" , "message" => "Sorry, You can not delete your own account"]);
    }
}

?>
```

We also don't have `api` folder and `deleteUser.php` file in our `source` tab but the payload (in our case payload is `id`)is being passed to it but and nothing comes in the response more than an error.
This picture would more clear the think

[image]

Alright, this was the issue I was facing until I use the `method: "POST"` in ajax call. As soon as I change the method from `"DELETE"` to `"POST"` it started working. Like this:

```
    $(document).on("click" , "#delete_button" , function(){
        const id = $(this).attr("data-delete_user_id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/deleteUser.php",
            method: "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify({id}),
            success: function (data) {
                const res = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    })
```

`The output in the console is`

[image]

As we already know that the `DELETE` method is specially used when we want to delete the record, but in my case, why `DELETE` method is not suitable to delete the user from the database?
Why I had to use the 'POST' method to avoid this issue?

Comment: Change this method `method: "DELETE",` to `method: "POST",`

Comment: Exactly, but why should i use method "POST" instead of "DELETE"?